# Best way to set environment variable and execute command in one line

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd, environment-variables, command-line-interface

I want to make a backup with PostGreSQL pg_dump command with command line like :

```
"<c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_dump>" -h localhost -p 5432 -d test_backup_bat -U user -f D:\destination_backup\test.backup
```

but I need to set PGPASSWORD before as environment variable to execute the backup command

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword
```

How can I make this in only one command line into Windows CLI ?

Comment: 1. `cmd /V /C set "PGPASSWORD=5432" ^& pg_dump -h localhost -p !PGPASSWORD! -d test_backup_bat -U user -f "D:\destination_backup\test.backup"`, or 2. `set "PGPASSWORD=5432" & call pg_dump -h localhost -p %^PGPASSWORD% -d test_backup_bat -U user -f "D:\destination_backup\test.backup"`

Comment: @aschipfl - Does this require a `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` statement in advance?

Comment: No, that's what `/V` (1.) or `call` (2.) is for. Anyway, I guess I misinterpreted `5432` as the password in your command line, which seems to be wrong (sorry, I don't know `pg_dump`)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting a variable and using it inside the same line in a batch file or a command line can be "tricky" as the full line/command is parsed before the variable is set.

BUT, in your case, you don't need to do anything special because you don't need to use the variable in the command except for setting it. The `pg_dump` just reads the contents of the environment variable from its own environment block that is inherited from the parent `cmd` process. If the parent process has the variable defined, then `pg_dump` can read it from its own copy.

So, you just need two commands (one to set the variable and one to start the new process) inside the same line, executed one after the other. This is done with the `&` operator:

```cmd
set "PGPASSWORD=myPassword" & "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_dump" -h localhost -p 5432 -d test_backup_bat -U user -f D:\destination_backup\test.backup
```

Comment: I've seen cases where `set PGPASSWORD=myPassword` behaves differently from `set "PGPASSWORD=myPassword"`, note the quotes. Any idea why that would be the case? I can't seem to find documentation on it

Comment: @solstice333, The quotes avoid the requirement for escaping when using special characters and the inclusion of additonal ending spaces in the value. This type of quoting is the usual way of using the `set` command to minimize errors. You can have problems (you can deal with it) when there is a quote inside the value to assign but otherwise it should work.

Comment: I see. But if no special characters are used and no trailing space is required, the semantics are supposed to be exactly the same right? To give some context, I'm seeing different results from doing `set XPDeprecationWarning=false && nmake foo` versus `set "XPDeprecationWarning=false" && nmake foo`, where the former has a warning and the latter has *no* warning. Seems kind of bizarre.

Comment: @solstice333, the line `set XPDeprecationWarning=false && nmake foo` includes a space (the space between `false` and `&&`) at the end of the variable while `set "XPDeprecationWarning=false" && nmake foo` does not include the space.

Answer (score 0):

To Set:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=mypasssword
```

To Verify:

```
echo %PGPASSWORD%
```

Comment: This is not one line solution. This is crucial as this wrapped into one line will break.